# how to add additional field in mongoose return data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

i have a mongoose api where i want to get data from two collections, the data from first collection i want to match it with data from another collection and set a additional field in the data return by first collection and send this data as response. i don't know how to add additional field to data return by mongoose. Can you please help me out

below is my api

```
exports.getSeriesWithNumbers = function(req, res){
    seriesModel.find({status:{$ne:'deleted'}}, function(err, data){
        if(data){
            data.forEach(function(record){
                console.log(record.series_name);
                numberRegisterModel.find({series:record.series_name, status:{$ne:'deleted'}}, function(err,ndata){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else if(ndata){
                        console.log(ndata);
                        record.push('canDelete');
                        record.set('canDelete', true);
                    }
                    else{
                        record.push('canDelete');
                        record.set("canDelete", false);
                    }

                    console.log("after if: " + record.canDelete);
                });

            });


            console.log(data);
           // res.json(data);
        }
        else{
            console.log('error: '+ err);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: So what are you asking? Is it how to add an additional field `canDelete` into each document returned and set `true/false`? Also why the lookup from another collection? Can you explain the relation, and perhaps the purpose of what you are doing this for, as there is likely a better approach than doing a lookup for every document in results.

Comment: you can use ref and populate the data

Comment: @BlakesSeven Hi, i have a list to display where in a have a checkbox for each record displayed. now while displaying the records list i want to make the checkbox disable and enable based on certain conditions. Here i am getting the records from first collection i.e. data from seriesModel and looking in another collection with the field from i am getting from series Model, if the records are found in the second collection then i want to add a new field in each document with true and false as value.

Comment: first of all record is not an array its an object if you want to set the value you can use record['propertyName']  = value ;

Comment: @Ahmer here 'propertyName' does not exists, i want to add a new 'propertyName' 'canDelete' to each record, i tired this. it is not working

Comment: can you post the data from the first collection and also the newly added field